# Hybris flexible extract order id which has more than 10 products

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to extract order id which has more than 10 products. Could you please suggest me the flexible search query.

Comment: select {o.code} from {Order as o JOIN OrderEntry as oe on {oe.order}={o.pk}} group by {o.code} having count({o.code})>10

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please use group by with having clause.

```
select {o.code} from {Order as o join OrderEntry as oe on {oe.order}={o.pk}}
group by {o.code} having count({o.code})>10
```

reference to use having clause:  [having clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)